# How to stop Redundancy in Displaying record from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am facing problem with redundant record from mysql how to avoid this in this particular query?

```
$sql = "SELECT  DISTINCT d.*,m.* 
        FROM df_job_meta m 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN df_job_post d ON d.ID = m.JOB_ID 
        WHERE (d.STATUS =:ACTIVE) 
        and ( m.VALUE LIKE :wha ) 
        and d.STATE LIKE :whe 
        order by d.ID DESC";
```

Comment: You have already done `SELECT DISTINCT`, how are you getting a redundant record?

Comment: What's the redundant data?

Comment: BTW your `where` clause turns your `left join` into an `inner join`

Comment: i am getting record from mysql with same id twice eg 105,105  and 107,107

Comment: What ID are you referencing, d.id or m.Job_Id?  If d.id, then you likely have a one to many relationship between df_job_meta and df_job_Post.  Where the same job_Post ID could have multiple meta data or vice versa.  Remove the m.* if you don't need any of the data and you're ID's will become unique...  Understand your data first  The entire row isn't a duplicate, otherwise the distinct would have removed it.  What data is different and do you need it, if you don't need the column, adjust your select...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `... GROUP BY d.ID` to get rid of the duplicate IDs

Comment: While this will definitely work in mySQL due to mySQLs extended group by, it will also eliminate data which may be relevant; and possibly return incorrect data as mySQL randomly selects the other fields values if they are not the same.